# Compound fields in search

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to get first name and last name from a related table

I've tried using an accessor on the related table which works fine when loading the page and for adding/editing but when searching it shows an error

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'FullName' in 'where clause'`

This column obviously does not exist.

So I have this in my related model

```
    {
        return $this->attributes['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['last_name'];
    }
```

And under the Backpack crud Controller I have

```
   $this->crud->addColumn([ // n-n relationship (with pivot table)
            'label' => 'Account', // Table column heading
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'user_id', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'entity' => 'user', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'FullName', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => "App\Models\BackpackUser", // foreign key model

        ]);
```

Where am I making a mistake, input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Right now I'm using a temporary workaround by creating a FullName field as a view that I reference in my modal

Answer (score 1):

That needs a real column.

You can use a view (like you already do) or a `model_function` column to format the table cell value in your model class - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-columns#model_function

Just see what's simpler for you.

*Note*: if ordering or searching doesn't work as expected see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-columns#custom-search-logic-for-columns and https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-columns#custom-order-logic-for-columns